# What is the best (efficient, logical) way to validate a value with multiple validators?

Tags: php, validation

it's probably quite a noob question, but I'm not an expert PHP developer and I was wondering what is the best (efficient, logical) way to write the following code:

```
function validate_1 ( $input ) {
  if ( mycondition ) {
    return $input;
  }
}

function validate_2 ( $input ) {
  if ( myOtherCondition ) {
    return $input;
  }
}

function validate ( $input ) {
  if ( validate_1( $input ) ) {
    return validate_1( $input );

  } else if ( validate_2( $input ) ) {
    return validate_2( $input );

  } else {
    return validate_last( $input );
  }
}

validate( 'a value' );
```

in this way I'm always executing the functions twice. Is that fine or is there a better way (php >= 5.2)?

Comment: Looks like lots of duplication, tends to not be efficient. But hard to refactor without know what the validations are doing. Them all returning the same value looks odd too.

Comment: Sorry, your code just doesn't make sense.

Comment: wow I probably overlooked at my code. It doesn't make sense, true. :) I probably just needed someone to say that... working alone can lead to paranoid :).

Comment: You're welcome. :-) I see you got a useful answer afterall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:
http://dsheiko.com/subpage/chain-of-responsibility-pattern

or do it like this with classes:

```
abstract class Validator {
 public function validate($args);
}
class Vali1 extends Validator {
 public function validate($args){
    #validate
    return $bool;#true or false
 }
}
class Vali2 extends Validator {
 public function validate($args){
    #validate
    return $bool;#true or false
 }
}

$validators = array(new Vali1,new Vali2);
$validated=null;
foreach($validators as $validator){
   $validated = $validator->validate($args);
}
```

or with functions :

```
$validators = array(
   function($args) {  retrun $bool;},
   function($args) {  retrun $bool;},
   function($args) {  retrun $bool;}
);
 $validated=null;
foreach($validators as $validator){
  $validated = $validator($args);
}
```

But that is just the basics. And there are more ways to rome.

update:

```
$count = count($validators);
$current = 0;
do{
 $result = $validators[$current++]($args);
}while(!$result && $current < = $count);
```

and then return $input in the function or NULL on not valid

Comment: even if I don't think I phrased the question well, I think you got the point. That was actually the pattern I was looking for, thanks.

Comment: no deal, its also good for me to help out here ;)

Comment: This is a good answer...one small tip: I would use `abstract public function validate` instead of `public function validate`...otherwise you'll have to define it in the abstract class (or else you'll get an error "Non-abstract method Validator::validate() must contain body" if you write the code exactly as shown here).

Answer (score 1):

Before you write such unreadable code, use some validation strategies like the Symfony validation component or just keep it simple and try to encapsulate your code in a class (e.g. OrderValidator) with one `public function validate($data)` and keep this method clean by writing small readable private functions you use in that public function.

Think of someone trying to understand the code. He is going to have a look at the validate method and if it's like this ...

```
public function validate($data) {
    return
        $this->isEachOrderClosed($data)
        && $this->hasAtLeastOneCustomer($data)
        && $this->isNotSent($data)
    ;
}
```

... he maybe needn't read the private methods and everything is clear.